# Llamado por voz

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito realizar un llamado a un turno (Por ejemplo: J203) por voz y sin necesidad de presionar ningún botón. Sólo que al cargar la página me haga el llamado una sola vez, y cuando recargue la página vuelva a hacerlo (O con el siguiente turno)

Acá el index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Siri</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="texto">
    <input type="button" id="hablar" value="Decir">
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Acá los estilos

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
}

body {
    background-color: #ededed;
}

div {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 50px;
}

input {
    padding: 9px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    width: 80%
}
input[type="button"] {
    width: 15%
}
```

Acá el javascript

```
document.getElementById('hablar').addEventListener("click",()=>{
    decir(document.getElementById("texto").value);
});

function decir(texto){
    speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(texto));
}
```

Comment: ¿ Cual es el problema ? No tienes mas que llamar a tu función `decir( )` **despues** de definirla, en cualquier parte de tu código.

Comment: Si, pero necesito que sea al cargar, sin necesidad de presionar algún botón

Comment: Sigo sin ver el problema. No tienes mas que engancharte al evento [`DOMContenLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). Me sorprende que conozcas la API `speechSynthesis` (que es experimental) y no conozcas el `DOMContentLoaded` de toda la vida O_O

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar jQuery para realizar una función al momento de cargar la pagina, utilizando lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  decir(document.getElementById("texto").value);
});
```

Solo es cuestion de que se inserte un dato en tus `<input>` al momento de recargar la pagina, y asi dentro del `$(document).ready();` puedes realizar tu funcion `decir();` al momento de recargar la pagina.
Espero te sirva.
Saludos!